# Реализация по второму клику jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, события

Добрый вечер ребят, делаю dropdown menu и хочу реализовать его на планшетах и мобилках так чтобы при первом клике оно разворачивалось а при втором осуществлялся переход по ссылке этого меню, что то вроде

```
if($("#element).click(function() {
   $("#element").dropdown();
if("#element").click(function() {
   location.href = $(this).attr('href');});});
```

подскажите если такое вообще возможно, или я не в том направлении мыслю?

Comment: ну если ты его уже раскрыл то можеш просто удалить обработчик и оставить голую ссылку , или повесить класс при клике по которому происходит переход по href

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если не принципиально использовать Jquery, то можно воспользоваться addEventListener и повесить обработчик событий на любой нужный тебе элемент меню.

https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Comment: Благодарю, но я так и не нашел решения в свое время пришлось отказаться от js и добавлять еще одну кнопку как раз для события выпадания, но ваш метод хорош, однозначно опробую его в будущем.

Comment: Пожалуйста! Тут похожий вопрос: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8996015/jquery-on-vs-javascript-addeventlistener Как раз касательно Jquery. Рекомендуют методы .on() либо .delegate()

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#element").click(function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass("clicked")) {
    location.href = $(this).attr('href');
  } else {
    $(this).addClass("clicked");
    $(this).dropdown();
  }
  return false;
});
```

Comment: а если кто то кликнет в другое место, ц-ц-ц не продумано, здесь нужен счетчик причем сбрасываемый

Comment: Откуда я знаю, что будет, если кто-то кликнет в другое место? Может планшет взорвется в руках у пользователя?

Comment: ну ты предложил самый простой вариант, который логически неверен. Да он выполняет функцию, но работает не правильно)